# QGIS LiDAR derived contour to Garmin GPS

Tags: qgis, gps, lidar, garmin

I have this neat little contour layer in QGIS Desktop 3.16.8 that I derived from LiDAR data. How can I send this as a vector map in my Garmin GPSMAP 64s? Those contour lines are 1m and so vector is definitely preferred. Everything I tried failed so far.

Comment: Export to GPS Exchange Format, (.gpx)?

Comment: Are you sure you want to load 1m contours on a Garmin device? This looks like a lot of lines on a small screen.

Answer (score 1):

The last time I was still paying attention to Garmin devices, the vector file format for was a proprietary format with a .img extension. The format has been reverse engineered and a mostly open toolchain exists for creating your own maps. A description of the process can be found [here](https://www.gpsfiledepot.com/tutorials/how-to-create-garmin-topo-maps---part-1---setup/). I would describe the process as "not for the faint of heart."

I suppose you could encode each contour as a track in a GPX file, as suggested by Mapperz, but you would have very little control over how this displays on the GPS. I would be concerned about how it would affect the rendering time on the display.

While I have a 76csx and have created my own .img files, I've pretty much abandoned Garmin handhelds in favor of the Avenza app on my iPhone (also available on Android). The display is infinitely superior and the free edition allows you to download three custom maps of your own creation at a time. In addition, you can overlay kmz files on any map, which would address your contours problem.

Comment: GPX does not work, it litterally freezes and there are simply too many contour lines. I've also used the GarminCustomMap plugin and it works, but this generates a kmz. Will try the lengthy tutorial and see if I can get it to work...

Answer (score 0):

There (at 2022) appear to be two main approaches for getting contour data into the Garmin .img format. Both involve several steps, and several different pieces of software - as Llaves says, "not for the faint of heart."

I'll try to give an outline of both, having spent several days trying to do exactly that.

My general recommendation would be to spend the time understanding the [mkgmap](https://www.mkgmap.org.uk/) option. The tools in this toolchain have a greater level of support and can be made to work across various OSs.

I've described the minimum steps to get a **small** contour map into Garmin. For large maps, there are extra steps to split the data into smaller pieces. If you want layers other than contours, extensions of the approaches below can be made to work with either toolchain.

## Mkgmap

The first approach uses QGIS, *ogr2osm* and *mkgmap*.

Within QGIS, add the following fields to your contour layer. This assumes that you've created contours with the default ELEV field:

1. `ele`: int, `to_int("ELEV")`
2. `contour`: Text(10), `'elevation'`
3. `contour_ext`: Text(16), calculated from ele. This field is optional. You can set the major and medium contour intervals. eg if you want 100m major contours and 50m medium contours (in contours with a 10m interval) you can use the following:

   `if("ele"/100 = floor("ele"/100),'elevation_major',if("ele"/50 = floor("ele"/50),'elevation_medium','elevation_minor'))`

These are the default contour-related tags used by *mkgmap*. You can define your own, but it's easier to use the pre-supplied ones. Save as a Shapefile, or some other OGR compliant file type.

Next, you need to install *[ogr2osm](https://github.com/roelderickx/ogr2osm)*. This has various dependencies. It's a python script so needs at least Python >= 3.7, which does come bundled with most recent versions of QGIS. You'll also need the [GDAL and lxml packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/). You can use git to install ogr2osm, or otherwise download a zip from Github. I would suggest just running ogr2osm as a module unless you know what you are doing. In Windows, run python from within an OSGEO4W shell. From the ogr2osm directory, a basic call is (if all files are in the same place):

```
python -m ogr2osm --split-ways 5000 -o contours.osm contours.shp
```

This will output a .osm file. Finally, run [mkgmap](https://www.mkgmap.org.uk/) over the .osm file created. Mkgmap has literally hundreds of options. The command below will get you a very basic contour map.

```
java -jar C:\Path\To\mkgmap.jar --mapname=88052140 --input-file=contours.osm
```

## cGPSMapper

The second approach uses QGIS, cGPSMapper, and several scripts and programs available from [GPSDepot](https://www.gpsfiledepot.com/tutorials/how-to-create-garmin-topo-maps/). Mainly suited for Windows as it uses Windows executables and batch files.

Within QGIS, add the following fields to your contour layer. This assumes that you've created contours with the default ELEV field:

1. NAME: Text(10), the elevation - `to_string(to_int("ELEV"))`
2. MP_TYPE: Text(15), calculated from ELEV. You can set the major and medium contour intervals. eg if you want 100m major contours and 50m medium contours (in contours with a 10m interval) you can use the following:

   `if("ELEV"/100 = floor("ELEV"/100),'0x22',if("ELEV"/50 = floor("ELEV"/50),'0x21','0x20'))`

Save as a Shapefile, with name Lines.shp

The shapefile needs to then be converted to a .mp file. See the last section of Part 8 of the tutorial on the GPSDepot site for a process for this. It uses GPSFDshp2mp and a batch file (ConvertSplit2mp.bat).

Finally, use [cGPSMapper](https://www.gpsfiledepot.com/tools/cgpsmapper.php), and another batch file (CompileMps.bat) to create a .img file.

There are many other steps on the GPSDepot website - this is the bare minimum for basic contours.

## Review

Either way, you will end up with a .img file.

If you want to look at it before loading on to your device, QMapShack seems fairly easy to load/view .img files. Just point it at the directory where the .img file is saved.